# How to achieve this site structure?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, web-parts, moss2007enterprisesearch

I need to develop a website that looks like this.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/452c36f514.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/452c36f514.jpg)

In central administration however, in the operations tab, It shows
Central Administration--> Operations.
But I checked, operations is not a subsite. Then what is it.
In my application, I always get Home--> Operations. To add to trouble,it changes the name at the top as Operations. I need to keep it central administration only.

Please help me sort this out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the parent site, goto to Site Actions -> Site Settings --> Top Link Bar

There you can add any link you want, wheter internal or external, or remove existing ones.

hth